# Transparent background Label without form

Tags: c#, label, transparent

I have `Label`and I want to make this label transparent and hide current form.
In form, I can use:

```
label1.Parent = //for example picture box
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But if I use for hide form following code:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
Region = new Region(label1.Bounds);
```

How can I make transparent `label`? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you using transparency to hide components, rather than just hiding them (e.g., something like control.visible = false)?

Comment: If I use `control.visible = false` I didn't see anything. I need only see transparent label without form. Like a splash intro.

Answer (score 0):

To make the form's background transparent, set the `TransparencyKey` property of the form to the form's background color.

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
```

Comment: Also hide the title by hiding all boxes and clearing the text! and make the formborderstyle=none..!